# Changing Layer Order with ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, draw-order, contents-pane

Working on a Python script that does some routine table management of a couple of feature classes. In one step I define a table join and then export that to a GDB. When that runs, it will add it to the Geodatabase and also add the new Feature Class as a layer to the table of contents. It always adds to the top of the Table of Contents, but I need it to be added to the bottom as the last item.

The problem that I am running into is that in my code, I define several local variables using an index from the Table of Contents like `old_sites = mapx.listLayers()[3]`

If I have this hardcoded and a new layer is added to the top, this layer is no longer indexed at position 3, it's now 4, but the code won't know that.

Is there a way to change the default add position to the bottom?

Comment: Hi Dave - from my understanding you are looking for the MoveLayer command. Unfortunately it doesn't work in arcpro. I've Logged a bug report here:
https://my.esri.com/#/support/bugs/BUG-000138288.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing your full workflow but can you use the wildcard option and the name of the layer to get the one you want, `listLayers ({wildcard})`

[help doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm)

> A wildcard is based on the layer name and is not case sensitive. A combination of asterisks (*) and characters can be used to help limit the resulting list.

Example:
`old_sites = mapx.listLayers('your layer name here')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

If the drawing order of your layer is important to you, and you are not satisfied [creating layer objects based on any drawing order](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347017/change-drawing-order-with-python-in-arcgis-pro) then you also have an optional parameter named `add_position` available with the `addLayer` method of the [Map class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm):

```
addLayer (add_layer_or_layerfile, {add_position})
```

`add_position` is:

> A constant that determines the placement of the added layer or layers
>   in a map.
>
> - AUTO_ARRANGE —Automatically places the layer or layers based on its layer weight rules and geometry.
> - BOTTOM —Places the layer or layers at the bottom of the TOC layer stack.
> - TOP —Places the layer or layers at the top of the TOC layer stack.
>
> (The default value is AUTO_ARRANGE)

There is also an `insertLayer` method that uses a parameter named `insert_position`:

```
insertLayer (reference_layer, insert_layer_or_layerfile, {insert_position})
```

`insert__position` is:

> A constant that determines the placement of the added layer or layers
>   relative to the reference_layer.
>
> - AFTER —Inserts the new layer after or below the reference layer.
> - BEFORE —Inserts the new layer before or above the reference layer.
>
> (The default value is BEFORE)